# Modificar XML en Python

Tags: python, xml

Tengo un problema debo iterar dentro del XML encontrar un error de tipeo y modificarlo. Contexto: el sistema que genera los XML de la empresa tuvo un error y le agrega al código postal 000 al final del mismo y a los mails les agrega .con al final reemplazarlo manualmente es imposible ya que generó 9.000 de estos. Aclaro que no tengo experiencia con archivos XML me dieron esta tarea a mi por saber un poco de Python

Comment: Puedes usar el modulo [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) el resto te toca aprenderlo por tu cuenta. Suerte!

Comment: ¿Qué tamaño tiene el XML? ¿Cabe entero en memoria si lo lees con `ElementTree.parse("fichero.xml")`, como te sugieren usar en una respuesta? Si te cabe, lo más sencillo podría ser usar una expresión XPath para encontrar los nodos a modificar. Para más detalles necesitaría una especificación más precisa del problema (un XML de ejemplo, aunque sea reducido, pero que presente el mismo nivel de anidamiento del original). Si no te cabe en memoria habría que usar otra estrategia basada en SAX.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Importa el módulo.
xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Crea un arbol y consigue su raíz.
arbol = ET.parse('nombre_xml.xml')
raiz = arbol.getroot()

# Una vez hecho esto, puedes empezar a iterar mediante raiz.iter() o raiz.findall(). Ej.
cadena = 'cadena que reemplazara' # por ejemplo.

for hijo in raiz.findall('./hijo/nieto'):
    hijo.find('codigo_postal').text = cadena
```

No sé si te puedo ayudar un poco más. Soy muy novato, espero que te sirva de ayuda. Un saludo.